# Create array of selected items in a list and display their JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to perform what seems like a simple task and display `<li>`'s for each item in a JSON object. Then, when I click each displayed item, get additional JSON info from all the selected items, and create an array that is stored in a variable for use later.

Here is my JSON. Nothing crazy, simple array of data.

```
[
  {
    "subCategory": "Foo",
    "total": 100,
    "converted": 25,
    "revenue": 500
  },
  {
    "subCategory": "Bar",
    "total": 100,
    "converted": 25,
    "revenue": 1000
  }
]
```

With my JS (using jQuery), I'm getting and displaying each item correctly, but I'm not getting the data that I want when i select an item that is getting displayed. In the following JS, I realize I'm not doing much beyond adding the class to the li displayed, but I'm stuck on how to go about getting the data for each selected item and over write the variables below.

```
(function(){

    $('.bubbles').on('click', 'li', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i, value){
            // Display bubbles
            $('.marketingBubbles').append("<li class='"+ value.leads + " "+ value.status + " "+ value.lift + "'>");

            // Get data and create arrays
            var totalArray = [value.total], // Get values from all totals
                convertedArray = [value.converted], // Get all values from converted
                revenueArray = [value.revenue]

            // Add up numbers in arrays
            var totalConverted = eval(convertedArray.join('+')), // Sum of all converted leads
                totalLeads = eval(totalArray.join('+')), // Sum of all total leads
                totalRevenue = eval(indicatorRevenue.join('+')) // Sum of all revenue    

        });
    });


})();
```

HTML

```
<ul class="marketingBubbles"></ul>
```

Eventually, i would like to take the values within an array, no matter how many times it is changed, perform some simple math operations with the data and display in various divs on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The `var totalArray = [value.total]` defines a local variable(destroyed at the end, everytime) `totalArray` for each `$.each` iteration. I don't think that's what you wish to do here

Comment: create variables before the `each` and add new value on each pass of the `each` loop

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, that makes sense, I understand the concept of scope and see how my code was structured wrong. How would I go about adding/passing the new value n each click of the li's that have the class of 'selected'?